# Dismiss MPMoviePlayerViewController on play error

Tags: iphone, dismiss, mpmovieplayer, mpmoviewcontroller

I have a problem with the MPMoviePlayerViewController: If the controller can't find the movie at the specified URL it displays a white screen and I can't make it go close.

This is how I start the movie player:

```
- (void) playVideo:(NSString*)path 
{
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

 double osversion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue];
 if (osversion >= 3.2) 
 {
  mplayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

  if (mplayerVC)
  {
   mplayerVC.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
   [mplayerVC.moviePlayer play];
   mplayerVC.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = TRUE;

  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mplayerVC];

  //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];    
  }

 }  
}
```

and this is how moviePlayBackDidFinish: method looks like this

```
    - (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
    {
     [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];  

     NSError* error = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"error"];
     if (error != nil)
     {
      // Movie ended with an error
      DLog(@"error=%@", error);
     }
     else 
     {
      // Movie ended successfully
     }

     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
     SAFE_DEL(mplayerVC);
    }
```

The white screen only happens if the URL is pointing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind guys, I figured it out.

Apparently in the moviePlaybackDidFinish method you have to call

```
[player stop];
```

before dismissing the controller.

Above, player is the MPMoviePlayerController object obtained like this:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
```